# Mock object of type android.content.res.Configuration and assign it a locale

Tags: java, android, mockito

I have a class where I am trying to retrieve the country of the device:

```
context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

Where `context` is of type: `android.content.Context`

So here, `context.getResources()` returns an object of type `android.content.res.Resources`.

On that object, `getConfiguration()` is called, which returns an object of type `android.content.res.Configuration`.

On that, I am accessing the field `locale`, which is of type `java.util.Locale`.

In a unit test, I am trying to mock this whole context:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, DEFAULT_COUNTRY);
configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setLocale(locale);
```

Here, however, I am getting an error because `setLocale` is implemented as:

```
public void setLocale(Locale loc) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

Alternatively, I tried mocking the whole `Configuration` class with Mockito:

```
mock(Configuration.class);
```

However, I am not able to do that because the class is declared `final`.

So then, how can I mock an object of type `android.content.res.Configuration` and give it a locale?

Answer (score 3):

This is how use `Mockito` I re-post my answer there too.

**Example**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.LocaleList;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.util.Locale;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test2 {

    @Mock
    Context mMockContext;

    @Test
    public void getLocal() {
        Resources resources = Mockito.mock(Resources.class);
        when(mMockContext.getResources()).thenReturn(resources);
        Configuration configuration = Mockito.mock(Configuration.class);
        when(mMockContext.getResources().getConfiguration()).thenReturn(configuration);
        LocaleList localeList = Mockito.mock(LocaleList.class);
        when(mMockContext.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales()).thenReturn(localeList);
        when(mMockContext.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0)).thenReturn(Locale.CANADA);
        System.out.println(mMockContext.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0));
    }
}
```

**System.out**

```
en_CA

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[Mockito Doc](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests)

From [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.res.Configuration.setLocale(Ljava/util/Locale;)V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51670058/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-android-content-res-configuration-setlocaleljava-u)

Comment: Works like a charm! It is important to mock the complete chain (`resources`, `configuration`, `localeList`), not just `localeList`