# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.res.Configuration.setLocale(Ljava/util/Locale;)V

Tags: android

I am trying to test my code by passing it a `null` locale from a unit test:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setLocale(null);
```

Here, `Configuration` is of type `android.content.res.Configuration`.

If I CMD-click on this method, I can see that it exists:

```
public void setLocale(@Nullable Locale loc) {
    setLocales(loc == null ? LocaleList.getEmptyLocaleList() : new LocaleList(loc));
}
```

However, I am getting an error saying that it does not exist.

Is this because my minimum supported API is 21 and the method is not part of that API?

Anyway, is there another way to pass a `Locale` to a `Configuration`?

Comment: I don't think is because you minimum api because the min is 17 `added in API level 17`

Comment: I do research and I find `Mockito` https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests but they don't work totally I need more research to know why when I set the `Local` when I get it is always `null` but they found the `method`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock object of type android.content.res.Configuration and assign it a locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51291388/mock-object-of-type-android-content-res-configuration-and-assign-it-a-locale)

Comment: The reason I flag this is because this can has been bounty to help other.

Comment: Is not exactly the same question but is the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think I find a solution for you. You must use `Mockito` to do this.

**Example**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.LocaleList;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.util.Locale;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test2 {

    @Mock
    Context mMockContext;

    @Test
    public void getLocal() {
        Resources resources = Mockito.mock(Resources.class);
        when(mMockContext.getResources()).thenReturn(resources);
        Configuration configuration = Mockito.mock(Configuration.class);
        when(mMockContext.getResources().getConfiguration()).thenReturn(configuration);
        LocaleList localeList = Mockito.mock(LocaleList.class);
        when(mMockContext.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales()).thenReturn(localeList);
        when(mMockContext.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0)).thenReturn(Locale.CANADA);
        System.out.println(mMockContext.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0));
    }
}
```

**System.out**

```
en_CA

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[Mockito Doc](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests)

[mockito](/questions/tagged/mockito)